# How do I make text filter case-insensitive?

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe, angular-pipe

My current text filter successfully filters an array and outputs only the exact case match. I want to be able to search without matching the case unaffecting the search results in their respective cases.

```
users = [
  {fname: 'John', lname: 'doe'},
  {fname: 'Jane', lname: 'Doe'}
];

<h3>USERS</h3>
<input type="text" Name="userSearch" [(ngModel)]="userSearch">

<ul *ngFor="let user of users">
  <li>{{ user.fname }} {{ user.lname }}</li>
</ul>
```

> Search Text: `doe` 
>   Search Result: `John doe` 
>   Expected Results: `John doe`,`Jane Doe`

Current text filter Pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'textFilter' })
export class TextFilter implements PipeTransform
{
  transform(value: any, term: any) {
    if (!term) { return value; }
    return value.filter((item: any) => {
      for (let prop in item) {
        if (typeof item[prop] === 'string' && item[prop].indexOf(term) > -1) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@Pipe({ name: 'textFilter' })
export class TextFilter implements PipeTransform
{
  transform(value: any, term: any) {
    if (!term) { return value; }
    return value.filter((item: any) => {
      for (let prop in item) {
        if (typeof item[prop] === 'string' && 
          item[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```